# Swift add Gesture to UIImageView?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uiimageview

Now i am working on IOS project with Swift!
I already made coverflow object.
And now i want some function to run when i click on each images in that coverflow.

I tried to add some gesture on it but seems didn't work.
This is my code below.

```
 func carousel(carousel: iCarousel!, viewForItemAtIndex index: Int, var reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView!
    {
        var label: UILabel! = nil
        var labelSecond: UILabel! = nil
        var labelVol: UILabel! = nil

        var viewRec: UITapGestureRecognizer! = nil

        var itemsVol = [itemsInside01.count,itemsInside02.count,itemsInside03.count,itemsInside04.count,itemsInside05.count]

        println(itemsVol[2])

        //create new view if no view is available for recycling
        if (view == nil)
        {
            //don't do anything specific to the index within
            //this `if (view == nil) {...}` statement because the view will be
            //recycled and used with other index values later
            view = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 156))
            (view as UIImageView!).image = UIImage(named: "coverFlowBg.png")
            view.contentMode = .Center


            var wBounds = view.bounds.width
            var hBounds = view.bounds.height
            var labelSize = CGRect(x: 0, y: hBounds, width: wBounds, height: 52)
            var labelSmallSize = CGRect(x: 0, y: hBounds + 30, width: wBounds, height: 24)

            label = UILabel()
            label.frame = labelSize
            label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            label.textAlignment = .Center
            label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            label.font = UIFont(name: "supermarket" , size: 18)
            label.tag = 1

            labelSecond = UILabel()
            labelSecond.frame = labelSize
            labelSecond.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            labelSecond.textAlignment = .Center
            labelSecond.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            labelSecond.font = UIFont(name: "supermarket" , size: 18)
            labelSecond.tag = 1

            labelVol = UILabel()
            labelVol.frame = labelSmallSize
            labelVol.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            labelVol.textAlignment = .Center
            labelVol.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            labelVol.font = UIFont(name: "supermarket" , size: 12)
            labelVol.tag = 1

            imageTypeIcon = UIImage(named: cardTypeImageSrc[index])
            imageTypeIconView = UIImageView(image: imageTypeIcon)
            imageTypeIconView.contentMode = .Center
            imageTypeIconView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: wBounds, height: hBounds)

            viewRec = UITapGestureRecognizer()
            viewRec.addTarget(self, action: "viewIsClicked:")

            imageTypeIconView.addGestureRecognizer(viewRec)
            imageTypeIconView.userInteractionEnabled = true

            view.addSubview(label)
            //view.addSubview(labelSecond)
            view.addSubview(labelVol)
            view.addSubview(imageTypeIconView)
        }
        else
        {
            //get a reference to the label in the recycled view
            label = view.viewWithTag(1) as UILabel!
        }

        //set item label
        //remember to always set any properties of your carousel item
        //views outside of the `if (view == nil) {...}` check otherwise
        //you'll get weird issues with carousel item content appearing
        //in the wrong place in the carousel
        label.text = "\(items[index])"
        //labelSecond.text = "\(items[index])"

        labelVol.text = "\(itemsVol[index]) " + "ชุดการ์ด"

        return view
    }

    func carousel(carousel: iCarousel!, valueForOption option: iCarouselOption, withDefault value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat
    {
        if (option == .Spacing)
        {
            return value * 1
        }
        return value
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func goBackToIndex(sender: AnyObject) {
        if let navController = self.navigationController {
            navController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        }
    }

    func viewIsClicked(){
        println("uuteosuteo")
    }
```

So if someone know why it didn't work please help me
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your function **viewIsClicked()** doesn't contain any parameters, but your selector contains a colon - "viewIsClicked:", so you probably getting runtime error.

Try to change:

```
    viewRec.addTarget(self, action: "viewIsClicked:")
```

To:

```
    viewRec.addTarget(self, action: "viewIsClicked")
```

Comment: This is correct. If you want access to the gesture (using the selector with a colon), you have to accept the gesture as a parameter:
`func viewIsClicked(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) { }`

Answer (score 1):

Changing following snippet of code will do your work

```
viewRec = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "viewIsClicked")
viewRec.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
viewRec.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
```